# Acting on every 100 elements of an array

Tags: powershell

I am using `Get-ADComputer` to return all the computers in Active Directory.

We intend to call the DELL Warranty web-service API and retrieve warranty information for each computer.

The DELL Warranty web-service takes a pipe separated list of service tags, maximum 100, and we have 1483 computers ...

So I need to act on every 100 elements of the array populated by my code, but am having trouble.

```
clear-host

   $Counter=0
   $ServiceTag::Empty
   $ServiceTagsMasterList=@()

(Get-ADComputer `
    -properties OperatingSystem -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} `
    |Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"}`
    |Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"})`
    | Select -Exp Name|ForEach-Object{
    $ServiceTag = $_.substring(3) #remove w7- l7- etc....    

if ($ServiceTag.Length -eq "7"){

        #write-host "service tag:" $ServiceTag
        $ServiceTagsMasterList += $ServiceTag + ','
        $Counter+=1    
      }
   }
   write-host $ServiceTagsMasterList.length, $Counter, $Counter % 100
   write-host $ServiceTagsMasterList
```

I am having trouble getting the `Mod` right - I expect `$Counter % 100` to return 14 with remainder 83, but the output is **1483 % 100**

I need to be able to call the DELL Warranty api for each block of 100 service tags, so I can either do it like that or perhaps split the array?

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gpunktschmitz already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48702401/1163423) whats wrong in your code. This is how your batch could look like:

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -properties OperatingSystem -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
    Select-Object -Expand 

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $computer.length; $i+=100)
{ 
    $computer | Select-Object -Skip $i -First 100 | ForEach-Object {
        # your code here
    }
}
```

Here an example with your 1483 computers:

```
$computer = 1 .. 1483  | ForEach-Object { "DellPc$($_)" }

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $computer.length; $i+=100)
{ 
    $computer | Select-Object -Skip $i -First 100 | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "batch: $i computer: $_"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to write it like this to be calculated:

```
write-host $ServiceTagsMasterList.length, $Counter, $($Counter % 100)
```

and % is the remainder not modulo
http://www.madwithpowershell.com/2016/11/powershell-modulus-operator-is.html

Comment: Thanks, and how would I find out how many whole hundreds - I tried `$($Counter/100)`?

Comment: `$([math]::Floor($Counter/100))`